# Selenium Python can't find the element

Tags: python, selenium

I want to find the element and check its stock status, but cannot find the element

[image: website screenshot]

[image: website screehshot 2]

[image: website screenshot 3]

[image: website screenshot 4]

my code:

```
while staleElement:

    driver.get(list_url) 

    list_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="a-spacing-none g-item-sortable"]')

    for item in list_items:
        basket = False
        try:
            basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="a-button-text a-text-center"]')
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="a-button-text a-text-center"]')

        print(basket[0].text)
```

console:

[image: SS]

Comment: any iframes involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the xpath's relative:

```
for item in list_items:
    basket = False
    try:
        basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class="a-button-text a-text-center"]')
    except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class="a-button-text a-text-center"]')
```